# MS Docs "Partitioned table parallelism" vs "Parallel query processing on partitioned tables and indexes"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2022

The Microsoft documentation speaks of 2 features for SQL Server 2019 regarding parallelism that look very similar, but they are most likely very different. These are "Partitioned table parallelism" under "RDBMS Scalability and Performance" and "Parallel query processing on partitioned tables and indexes" under "Data Warehouse". So basically my question is if anyone knows what the exact difference is between the two? I have tried to look this up, but can't seem to find it anywhere. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16 for SQL server 2019 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16 for SQL Server 2022

What Iam assuming is that "Partitioned table parallelism" under "RDBMS Scalability and Performance" is just the basic parallelism, which would apply to a table that is partitioned. In other words, can a query use parallelism in it's query plan when querying one or more partitioned tables. An example I think would be a table scan against a partitioned table using parallelism. Do the threads get distributed across the partitions required here btw (in combination with partition elimination maybe)?

For "Parallel query processing on partitioned tables and indexes" under "Data Warehouse" I assume that with "Data Warehouse" Microsoft means SSIS in this case? What I also think is that this feature maybe enables the developer to run multiple queries at the same time that query partitioned tables, which would otherwise mean that with Standard Edition you can only run 1 query using partitioned tables at a time? Which would be eh... 'surprising'.

I also read there was an issue with the SQL Server 2016 documentation, as per this article from Erik Darling: https://erikdarlingdata.com/partitioning-and-parallelism/ , but that does not anwser my specific question.

I hope someone can enlighten me. :-)

Comment: Update: I have opened an issue on GitHub via the Microsoft documentation page: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/8840#issuecomment-1505964792